# Objective-C subclass and base class casting

Tags: objective-c, subclass, radix

I'm going to create a base class that implements very similar functions for all of the subclasses.  This was answered in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993431/objective-c-protocol-vs-inheritance-vs-extending).  But what I need to know now is if/how I can cast various functions (in the base class) to return the subclass object.  This is both for a given function but also a function call in it.

(I'm working with CoreData by the way)

As a function within the base class (this is from a class that is going to become my subclass)

```
+(Structure *)fetchStructureByID:(NSNumber *)structureID inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {...}
```

And as a function call within a given function:

```
Structure *newStructure = [Structure fetchStructureByID:[currentDictionary objectForKey:@"myId"]];
                                              inContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Structure is one of my subclasses, so I need to rewrite both of these so that they are "generic" and can be applied to other subclasses (whoever is calling the function).

How do I do that?

Update: I just realized that in the second part there are actually two issues.  You can't change [Structure fetch...] to [self fetch...] because it is a class method, not an instance method.  How do I get around that too?

Comment: Constructor/initializer methods generally return `id` for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I believe the key is the [self class] idiom.

As far as your update goes requesting a way to call a class method on the current class you can use `[self class]`. As in:

```
Structure *newStructure = [[self class] fetchStructureByID:[currentDictionary 
                                              objectForKey:@"myId"]];
                                                 inContext:managedObjectContext];
```

EDIT: I redid this to return `id` per @rpetrich's comment -- much cleaner and avoids the need for `-isKindOfClass:` as long as you're sure of the type of the instance you're calling `-createConfiguredObject` on.

As for the first part, you could just return an `id` (pointer to any object) and document that it will return an instance of the same class it's called upon. Then in the code you need to use [self class] anywhere you instantiate a new object in a method.

e.g. if you have a `-createConfiguredObject` method which returns an instance of the same class it's called on, it would be implemented as follows:

```
// Returns an instance of the same class as the instance it was called on.
// This is true even if the method was declared in a base class.
-(id) createConfiguredObject {
    Structure *newObject = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    // When this method is called on a subclass newObject is actually
    // an instance of that subclass
    // Configure newObject
    return newObject;
}
```

You can then use this in code as follows:

```
StructureSubclass *subclass = [[[StructureSubclass alloc] init] autorelease];
subclass.name = @"subclass";

// No need to cast or use isKindOfClass: here because returned object is of type id
// and documented to return instance of the same type.
StructureSubclass *configuredSubclass = [[subclass createConfiguredObject] autorelease];
configuredSubclass.name = @"configuredSubclass";
```

For reference, what I was referring to with `-isKindOfClass:` and casting to the proper subclass is as follows:

```
Structure *structure;
// Do stuff
// I believe structure is now pointing to an object of type StructureSubclass
// and I want to call a method only present on StructureSubclass.
if ([structure isKindOfClass:[StrucutreSubclass class]]) {
    // It is indeed of type StructureSubclass (or a subclass of same)
    // so cast the pointer to StructureSubclass *
    StructureSubclass *subclass = (StructureSubclass *)structure;
    // the name property is only available on StructureSubclass.
    subclass.name = @"myname";
} else {
    NSLog(@"structure was not an instance of StructureSubclass when it was expected it would be.");
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before casting to the proper subclass"?  

This has helped me a lot so far, there are still a few aspects I'm trying to work out.  Especially when trying to set a variable like newObject.name = ... since Structure (in your case the base class) doesn't have name, but the subclass(es) do.  In that case do I just need to make Structure look like it has those variables too?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  It took me awhile to implement it and all.  This really helped a lot, thank you.